# Creating Tkinter dialog box in arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, python-addin, tkinter

I would like to create a dialog box which pops up when the user click on a button from a Python Add-In toolbar.

The user will navigate to their preferred file and select any shapefiles they wish to add to ArcMap.

I found this code:

```
    import Tkinter, tkFileDialog
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    file_path = tkFileDialog.askopenfile()
```

but the dialog box is ALMOST opening and then ArcMap crashes.

Comment: Use PyQT instead

Comment: I am not familiar with PyQT. Is that another programming language?

Comment: It's another graphics library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using a python addin, you could use the [`pythonaddins.OpenDialog`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000021000000) method.
Slightly modified example based on the [documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000021000000):

> This add-in button uses OpenDialog() to select a set of layer files
>   and adds each layer to the selected data frame.

```
import arcpy
import pythonaddins

class AddLayers(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
    def onClick(self):
        layer_files = pythonaddins.OpenDialog('Select Layers', True, r'C:\GISData', 'Add')
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        df = mxd.activeDataFrame
        for dataset in datasets:
            layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer(dataset)
            arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer)
```