# Trying to use Tkinter to open dialog box in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, tkinter

The following script works great from the command line but crashes from the pythonaddin:

```
import Tkinter

import tkFileDialog
root = Tkinter.Tk()
root.withdraw()
pathtest = tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
print pathtest
```

`pathtest = pythonaddins.OpenDialog('Open Item', True)` does not work for me because it suppresses filetypes that I need to see (pdf).

I know this is a [duplicate question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143053/creating-tkinter-dialog-box-in-arcpy) but I just joined the site and could not comment on other posts.

Comment: Using Tkinter or any other python gui-library is not supported for python-addins. The only supported option is using C#/arcobjects instead.

Comment: Anyone have an idea of how to use the pythonaddins.OpenDialog() without it suppressing file extensions.

Comment: pythonaddins.OpenDialog is only for browsing for spatial datasets. You could try PyQT per the suggestion by Jason Scheirer (an ESRI software developer) in the [question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/143053/2856) you linked to.

Comment: Will I have the same issue with PyQT that I had with Tkinter?

Comment: @Brad No idea, never tried it. But given that the suggestion was made by an ESRI employee (who I understand developed much of the ArcGIS python stack), I suggest you give it a go.

Answer (score 1):

It is technically possible to use Tkinter in arcpy / python addins using multiprocessing, but this is quite complicated and not supported or recommended by ESRI. They recommend using C# instead of python for GUI development.

See [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133354/recomendations-about-graphic-interface-for-arcpy-python-script) and 
http://anothergisblog.blogspot.se/2013/07/python-add-ins-and-tkinter.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try using native win32 dialogs. You'd need to have [pywin32](https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) installed first (pip installable version is [`pypiwin32`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypiwin32)), then you could do something like:

```
import win32ui
dlg = win32ui.CreateFileDialog(1, ".pdf", "Default File Name.pdf", 
                               0, "PDF Files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All Files (*.*)|*.*|")
dlg.DoModal()
print dlg.GetPathName()
del dlg
```